# basic python module design question

Tags: python

I have:

```
lib/
lib/__init__.py
lib/game.py
```

In `__init__.py` I'd like to define a variable that can be accessed by any class inside lib, like so:

```
BASE = 'http://www.whatever.com'
```

And then inside game.py, acces it inside in the Game class:

```
class Game:

def __init__(self, game_id):
    self.game_id = game_id

    url = '%syear_%s/month_%s/day_%s/%s/' % (lib.BASE, year, month, day, game_id)
```

Yeah so clearly 'lib.BASE' isn't right- what's the convention here? Is there a tidier, more pythonic way to handle what I'd call package-global variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

So you could have a `lib/settings.py` file which contains the line

```
BASE = 'http://www.whatever.com'
```

and then say

```
from settings import *
```

in `game.py` you should then be able to write

```
url = '%syear_%s/month_%s/day_%s/%s/' % (BASE, year, month, day, game_id)
```